# Floating one DIV left and another right within a parent container using dynamic, relative positioning

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have a parent container within which i would like to position a text element that fills the entire width UNTIL it hits the limit, which should be defined by an image that is gravitated to the right side of the parent container.

Unfortunately, whatever i try, the text remains covering the full width and the image appears below the text block.

```
<div class="subContext">
    <div class="description">
        This text should break automatically where the image box starts. This text should break automatically where the image box starts. This text should break automatically where the image box starts. This text should break automatically where the image box starts. This text should break automatically where the image box starts. 
    </div>
    <div class="boxImage">
        <img src="about:blank" alt="I want to be on the right" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[Please see my JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dShYL/3/)

What am i doing wrong?

I am looking for a cross-browser solution with backwards compatibility to at least IE 8 **and** no javascript usage.

**NOTE:** I felt that this must be extremely basic CSS. Still do. Yet i have searched and tried many possible solutions, but none worked for me. I may just be missing crucial key information / understanding.

Comment: the .boxImage needs to come before the .description in the html, OR a width needs to be set on the .description

Comment: Setting a width is not an option, i need full scalability. I tried changing the markup order as you suggested, to no avail. If i do, the boxImage is displayed ABOVE the text but nothing else changes.

Comment: Thanks. I get your point now. Watson applied that, but added what was missing: the removal of the float:left statement. Thank You though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I think this is what you want!](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/dShYL/5/)

I took the `float: left;` out of this and re-ordered your HTML.

```
.contentBox .contentArea-inner .subContext .description {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="boxImage">
    <img src="/img/dev/contentBoxSymbolicImage.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="description">
 This is just a blindtext. This is just a blindtext. This is just a blindtext. This is just a blindtext. This is just a blindtext. This is just a blindtext. This is just a blindtext. This is just a blindtext. This is just a blindtext. This is just a blindtext. This is just a blindtext. This is just a blindtext. 
</div>
```

Comment: Absolutely, sir. 100%. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dShYL/10/) with what you're after.

I simply rearranged some HTML:

```
<div class="subContext">
    <div class="boxImage">
        <img src="/img/dev/contentBoxSymbolicImage.jpg" />
    </div> 
    This is just a blindtext. This is just a blindtext. This is just a blindtext. This is just a blindtext. This is just a blindtext. This is just a blindtext. This is just a blindtext. This is just a blindtext. This is just a blindtext. This is just a blindtext. This is just a blindtext. This is just a blindtext. 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this satisfies your requirements, but here is one method:

I removed the `float` from `div.description` and moved it above the image in the HTML.
The description will now wrap around the floated image.

One caveat is that the text will wrap under the image if it is taller than the image, but I'm not sure whether this is undesirable for you.

```
.contentBox .contentArea-inner .subContext .description {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    // removed float
}
```

```
<div class="boxImage">
    <img src="/img/dev/contentBoxSymbolicImage.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="description"> ... </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dShYL/4/

Comment: @watson Looks like we both had the same idea ;)

Comment: ya -- standard solution :)

Comment: Yep, you both went the right way. Watson came 7 seconds earlier, so he gets the answer accepted, but thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

Move the image before the description and remove the `float: left` from the description div

HTML

```
<div class="subContext">
    <div class="boxImage">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" />
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        This is just a blindtext. This is just a blindtext. ... 
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dShYL/11/)

Floating an element means roughly, take it out of the normal flow, place it at the left or right of its container and let the *following* elements float around it.

Answer (score 0):

Giving width:85% for description solved the issue for me.
http://jsfiddle.net/dShYL/8/

If the image size is going to be different for each , then js would be the way to go but for 50*50, width 85% - 90% should solve it

```
.contentBox .contentArea-inner .subContext .description {
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        float: left;
        width:85%;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify a width that is less than 100% for your div .description. (since the image is 50px wide, it needs to actually be less than 100%- 50px)

```
.description { width: 75%; }
```

working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dShYL/6/

The reason why:
Floating makes a block level element's width dependent on its children. It will expand to at least the width of its parent, and since your content inside is large enough it makes it expand to the full width.

You could also change the order of the .description and .boxImage to make .boxImage come first. This isn't semantically correct anymore though, but works if you don't want to specify a fixed width for the .description